# Bing Webmaster Tools "Discovered but not crawled", How to Fix it?

Tags: search, indexing, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

I have a website created in 2018. It is performing well in Google Search. But it is not indexed in Bing Search. I have registered my website to Bing Webmaster Tools, and even integrated with IndexNow. I also submitted individual URL using URL submission regularly.

In the Site Explorer, it looks like almost all of my page is being Excluded. But i never exclude nor remove any page.

In the Bing Index section of URL Inspection, it says "Discovered but not crawled"
[image: Bing Index]

But in the Live URL section, it says "URL can be indexed by Bing"
[image: Live URL]

I think my website got blocked by Bing for some reason. I have sent email to Bing support several times but still no respond at all. Did anyone experience something similar?

My website is [kaptentekno.com](https://kaptentekno.com/)

I have followed the Bing Webmaster Guidelines, and ask Bing support by email but still no respond.
I want my website to be indexed in Bing Search.